# Square brackets around a top aligned array

Tags: arrays

I have this code

```
\[\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\text{word} & \\
\text{HEAD} & \begin{array}[t]{ll}
          \text{det} & \\
          \text{AGR} & \begin{array}[t]{lr}
                \text{agr-cat-pg} & \\
                \text{NUM} & ^{\color{green}[1]}\text{sg} \\
                \text{PER} & \text{ter} \\
                \text{GEN} & ^{\color{green}[2]}\text{fe}
                \end{array}
         \end{array} \\ \\
\text{VAL} & \begin{array}[t]{ll}
            \text{val-cat} & \\
            \text{SPR} & <> \\
            \text{COMPS} & <> \\
            \text{MOD} & <>
         \end{array}
\end{array}\right]\]
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

Now I want to enclose the `det` matrix inside square brackets like this:

[image]

but when I add `\left[ ... \right]` I get an undesired result:

```
\[\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\text{word} & \\
\text{HEAD} & \left[\begin{array}[t]{ll}
          \text{det} & \\
          \text{AGR} & \begin{array}[t]{lr}
                \text{agr-cat-pg} & \\
                \text{NUM} & ^{\color{green}[1]}\text{sg} \\
                \text{PER} & \text{ter} \\
                \text{GEN} & ^{\color{green}[2]}\text{fe}
                \end{array}
         \end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{VAL} & \begin{array}[t]{ll}
            \text{val-cat} & \\
            \text{SPR} & <> \\
            \text{COMPS} & <> \\
            \text{MOD} & <>
         \end{array}
\end{array}\right]\]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

How can I solve it? Other solutions involving a different environment than `array` are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a `2x2` matrix with `\text{word\\HEAD}` or something like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `delarray`. I added also some tricks to avoid `\text`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{delarray,array,xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}\lbrack{LL}\rbrack
word & \\
HEAD & \begin{array}[t]\lbrack{LL}\rbrack
          det & \\
          AGR & \begin{array}[t]{LR}
                agr-cat-pg & \\
                NUM & \textsuperscript{\color{green}[1]}sg \\
                PER & ter \\
                GEN & \textsuperscript{\color{green}[2]}fe
                \end{array}
         \end{array} \\ \\
VAL & \begin{array}[t]\lbrack{LL}\rbrack
            val-cat & \\
            SPR & <> \\
            COMPS & <> \\
            MOD & <>
         \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg !

Answer (score 4):

With the package `nicematrix`, you only have to replace one of your `{array}` by  `{bNiceArray}` and to compile twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\text{word} & \\
\text{HEAD} & \begin{bNiceArray}[t]{ll}
          \text{det} & \\
          \text{AGR} & \begin{array}[t]{lr}
                \text{agr-cat-pg} & \\
                \text{NUM} & ^{\color{green}[1]}\text{sg} \\
                \text{PER} & \text{ter} \\
                \text{GEN} & ^{\color{green}[2]}\text{fe}
                \end{array}
         \end{bNiceArray} \\ \\
\text{VAL} & \begin{array}[t]{ll}
            \text{val-cat} & \\
            \text{SPR} & <> \\
            \text{COMPS} & <> \\
            \text{MOD} & <>
         \end{array}
\end{array}\right]\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]